# What are the differences in EF when using your own Insert, Update and Delete Functions?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am looking into adding history tables to my database.  The easiest way is to intercept all Insert, Update and Delete calls that EF Makes and add in a merge that will also insert a history row into a history table.

Right now all my Entities just let EF figure out how to do the inserts, updates and deletes.

If I go and add in stored procedures (instead of the EF Generated stuff) will EF still function the same on the business tier?

Or does it change how I have to work with my entities?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Everything works the same, it is transparent.

Stored procedures need to return the rows affected, in order for EF to know that the update succeeded or not. Additionally, if you do an update and need to map any property back to your entity (e.g. timestamps) you must select them in the sproc and then map them back in the EF designer (since you can only have one output parameter, and that should be the rows affected).

You might consider using triggers on the DB to solve your issue, though?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Triggers have a very negative stigma at my company.  And as I am still in development, I think the sproc solution will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in stored procedures means that you will write all inserts, updates and deletes yourselves. It is like throwing 30% of feature set (and 50% productivity) away. Create audit records in your application and save them together with main records through EF.